# ubuntu jenkins install failing ~ jenkins stop/pre-start, process 22907 ... nada

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, installation

I currently have apache2 and tomcat7 running (and serving sites), and want to get jenkins running.

I've tried once before, a while ago, and decided to purge the current installation before moving forward.

```
sudo apt-get remove jenkins
sudo apt-get purge jenkins
```

Then I:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jenkins
```

and it seems to fail starting up...

> ....
>   Unpacking jenkins (from .../jenkins_1.424.6+dfsg-1_all.deb) ...
>   Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
>   Setting up jenkins (1.424.6+dfsg-1) ...
>   jenkins stop/pre-start, process 22907
>   ...

```
xxx:/var/log$ sudo service jenkins status
```

> jenkins stop/waiting

```
xxx:/var/log$ sudo service jenkins restart
```

> stop: Unknown instance:    jenkins stop/pre-start, process 31663

/var/log/jenkins/ is empty, and I can't seem to find anything useful in /var/log/*.  I do see, in auth.log, a jenkins user being setup.

Any ideas? : /

Comment: Anything useful in /var/log/syslog?

Comment: Try looking into /var/log/upstart/jenkins.log which may give you further information about what the process won't successful start

Answer (score 1):

Purge will fail if the package is not installed.  I see you did the following.

```
sudo apt-get remove jenkins
sudo apt-get purge jenkins
```

Instead, temporarily set the sources.list to the original, and run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jenkins
sudo apt-get purge jenkins
```

Then you can put your mods back and install the non-distro version.

Answer (score 0):

`/var/log/upstart/jenkins.log` will give Upstart's view of whether or not it thinks the Jenkins service is running or should be running.

`stop/pre-start` means that the `pre-start` stanza of `/etc/init/jenkins.conf` is stopping the service - for example, because it's missing a config file, or because it's been disabled under `/etc/default/jenkins`, or similar.